# Sony Hi-res Audio Player：windowリサイズ

Tags: macos

僭越ながら、プログラムに詳しい訳ではないのに投稿させていただきます。
mac環境で
どうしてもSony Hi-res Audio Playerのサイズ変更あるいは最大化をしたいのです。
900曲程入れていると画面サイズの狭さに困ります。
[image: ![画像の説明をここに入力]
↑このウインドウサイズで固定されている。同時20曲くらいしか表示できない。

【取り組んだ事】
Maximizer：
Cocoaアプリ ウインドウを最大化できるが Lion時代のSIMBLツールのプラグイン。
OSがSierraでSystem Integrity Protecton (SIP)がある為、
SIMBLを有効化するべくSIPをオフにする必要があり、
リカバリーモード（起動中に ⌘＋R）から
ターミナル $ csrutil disableコマンドでSIPをオフ →再起動 → SIMBLをインストール。
「~/ライブラリ/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins」の中に「Maximizer.bundle」を入れる。
 再度ターミナルで $ csrutil enable によりSIPをオン。
まったくフルスクリーンにならず。

MySIMBL：
別のSIMBLアプリを見つけたので 上記と同様に実施。結果も同じくNG。

Carbonアプリなのか？：
そもそもSony Hi-res Audio Player がCocoaアプリではないのではと思い、
Carbonアプリでウインドウリサイズ ツールを探すが 見つからなかった。

.plistファイル（ユーザーライブラリ preference内 & アプリ内）：
Finder内 Sony Hi-res Audio Player アプリ関係ファイルを漁り倒して、
該当項目を見つけようと ファイルを全て目視。
.plist が関係ありそうだと睨み、Prefs Editor及びxcodeで編集。
NSwindowFrame:App Window Position の赤丸部分だろうと思うのですが、
何度 変更しても元に戻ってしまう。
一応、ターミナル $ sudo killall cfprefsd で
plistキャッシュをクリアしたが、変更が固定せず。

以上です。
xcodeで.nibファイルを編集するべきなのかと思いつつも、
xcodeの使い方がわからずストップしています。
皆さん、
macにおいてSony Hi-res Audio Playerの様にウインドウサイズ固定のアプリを
サイズ変更する方法をご教示いただけないでしょうか。
何卒、宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
現在のOS-Xバージョンだと.nibファイルがコンパイルされているとの事で、
ターミナル plutil -convert xml1 （ファイル名）.nib でxmlに変換し、
xcode（テキストエディタでも良い）で表示。
該当箇所であろう所を探し出し、1200, 950へ変更。
ウインドウは妙な色ですが、36曲表示できるので、ひとまず目標達成できました。